# Text has wrong x position after being exported as a string and then imported from loadSVGFromString

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I have a project where I want the user to be able to add different shapes or text to a canvas via fabric.js, export it as a `SVGstring` and then import it as a `SVGstring` on another canvas.

The positioning on the `x-axis` works just fine if I stick to normal shapes, like rectangles. However, the position on the `x-axis` has an mysterious offset when I export and import a Text-object (created by fabric.js)

I've created this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/nm56BRl8SCk3CKYmGplh?p=info) in order to show you what I mean. Click "save" for the top canvas to be exported and then imported on the canvas at the bottom. The rectangle works fine.

Why is it adding a `x-offset` and how do I fix it?

A snippet from that Plunker is required by SO:

```
function saveDrawing() {
  console.log('Lets Draw');
  var drawing = canvas.toSVG();
  var showCanvas = new fabric.Canvas('show');
  fabric.loadSVGFromString(drawing, function (objects, options) {
    console.log(objects, options);
    objects.forEach(function (object) {
      showCanvas.add(object);
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I seem to have found the "solution" myself. This is an open [issue](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/1280) Fabric.js has been having for a long time. One way to work around this problem is to use another way of exporting and importing drawings. I've updated the original Plunker with my solution. Basically you just use JSON for importing/exporting instead of a SVGstring.